# How to make the jump from consumer support to enterprise support?

Tags: untagged

I am currently a high level consumer break/fix technician responsible for about 300-400 repairs a month. I am good at my job, but bored, and I want to move into the enterprise side of my company, dealing with Server 2008 R2 and exchange and switches and routers that cost more than I make in a month.

How do I make this transition? Whats the best thing to learn first? Is there a standard trajectory for making this leap from consumer to business? I am full time employed, so going back to school is not a great option, but I have no life, so spending my nights and weekends reading and practicing is totally within my realm.

I am basically overwhelmed by the number of things to learn, and looking for any advice you may have on the best way to proceed.

PS - I apologize if this is a not quite the right forum for this, I know its not a technical question exactly, but I also know the sorts of people I want to answer this question are reading this website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should start by telling somebody at your company that this is what you desire to do. Any company worth working at should be receptive and supportive of your goals. Try building a relationship with one of the managers in the enterprise side of your company. Let them know what your desires are and what your current track record looks like in consumer support. If you're really good at consumer support, ask your current manager to help you start this migration.

Any advice we give you here can only go so far. Since you want to move up in your current company the best people to help you out with that are managers at your current company.

Comment: +1 - this is exactly what I did when I was doing phone tech support. I told my boss that I was looking for something more and would be actively searching for other work. The next day he asked me for my résumé and he set me up with a job with a company that he used as a contractor. 5 years later I'm still there, and actually still working with my old company, but as a contractor, earning considerably more money.

Comment: Thanks much, somehow strikes me as blindingly obvious now, but never actually considered asking my boss about it...probably a good step 1.